# Error when rendering html/css code to pdf with dompdf or tcpd

Tags: php, tcpdf, dompdf, laravel-5.7

By entering the html / css code to the function of dompdf, this prints a wrong pdf, where all the text is overwritten on the same line and makes nonsense page breaks

I tried to print the same html with tcpdf and other applications without getting the expected results, all the words are always rendered in the same line, and the css is not shown
[image]

This is the the c ode html of what i want to print in pdf
[image]

This is my file controller to print the PDF

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Files;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Elibyy\TCPDF\Facades\TCPDF;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

public function index()
{
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    http_response_code(200);
    include 'l_vars/planilla_solicitud_logistica.php';

   $dompdf = new Dompdf();
   $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
   $dompdf->loadHtml($planilla);
   $dompdf->render();
   $dompdf->stream();      
}
```

This is the html code of the spreadsheet that I want to process in a pdf, this information must be dynamic since it will feed from the database

```
<style> 
    .bloque{
        display : table;
        border  : 1px solid black;
        width   : 100%;
    }
    .planilla{
        width  : 216mm;
        height : 279mm;
        border : 1px solid black;
        padding: 2.5cm 2cm;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: initial;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
    .logo{
        margin: 15px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .header{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .databloq{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .databloq{
        font-size: 0.5rem;
    }
    .logocontainer{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: columns;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .header .bloque{
        height: 2.55cm;
    }
    .bloqrow{
        display: flex;
        border: 1px solid black;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .header div {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .campo{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: .7cm;
        font-size: .65rem;
    }
    .campor{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 1.2cm;
        font-size: .9rem;
    }
    .formbloq{
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
    }
    .titulo{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #BBBDC0;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: .75rem;
        height: .5cm;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .checkox{
        width: 10px;
        height:10px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
    .check{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-content: flex-start
    }
    .labelgrey{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .sign{
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: .7cm;
        font-size: .7rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="planilla" id="content">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="bloque logocontainer" style="width: 40%;">
                <img class="logo" src="spsapplogo.png" alt="Logo de Southern Procurement Services">
            </div>
            <div class="bloque" style="text-align:center;font-size:1.3rem">
                <strong>Solicitud de Logistica de Viajes</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="databloq" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="bloqrow">
                    Codigo: SPS-FAD-007
                </div>
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; height: 100%;">
                    <div class="bloqrow" style="height: auto;width: 100%;">
                        Edicion: 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="bloqrow" style="height: auto;width: 100%;">
                        Revision: 0
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bloqrow">
                    Pag 1 de 2
                </div>
                <div class="bloqrow">
                    Fecha 17/10/2018
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="titulo">
            Datos del Solicitante
        </div>

        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 60%;">
                <div class="label">Nombre y Apellido del Solicitante</div>
                <div class="input"> <strong>Eleazar Ortega</strong> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="label">Cedula de Identidad</div>
                <div class="input"> <strong>V. 20.616.897</strong> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="label">Unidad o Area</div>
                <div class="input"> <strong>IT</strong> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="label">Sede</div>
                <div class="input"> <strong>Chuao</strong> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 25%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Solicitud</div>
                <div class="input"> <strong>01/01/2023</strong> </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="titulo">
            NACIONAL (VENEZUELA)
        </div>

        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="check"> 
                    <div class="text">Traslado en Vehiculo de la Empresa</div>
                    <div class="checkox"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 70%; background-color: #BBBDC0;">
                <div class="labelgrey"> 
                    Motivo del Viaje
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="check"> 
                    <div class="text">Traslado a Aeropuerto</div>
                    <div class="checkox"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 70%;">
                <div class="labelgrey"> 

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="titulo">
            Tipo de Traslado
        </div>
        <div class="titulo">
            Traslado Terrestre Nacional (Venezuela)
        </div>

        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Origen y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label">Tiempo de Espera</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Destino y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Retorno: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Origen y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label">Tiempo de Espera</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Destino y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Retorno: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Origen y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label">Tiempo de Espera</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Destino y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Retorno: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="titulo">
            Traslado Terrestre Urbano (Venezuela)
        </div>

        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Origen y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label">Tiempo de Espera</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Destino y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Retorno: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Origen y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label">Tiempo de Espera</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Destino y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Retorno: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Origen y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label">Tiempo de Espera</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Destino y/o Direccion</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Retorno: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 15%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="titulo">
            Traslado Terrestre Urbano (Venezuela)
        </div>

        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Origen</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Destino</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Retorno: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Origen</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Destino</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Retorno: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Origen</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Destino</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 20%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Retorno: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 10%;">
                <div class="label">Hora: <strong> 10:00 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="titulo">
            Hospedaje 
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Entrada: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Lugar o Ciudad: <strong>Cabimas Hotel Europa</strong></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Entrada: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Lugar o Ciudad: <strong>Cabimas Hotel Europa</strong></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Entrada: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 30%;">
                <div class="label">Fecha de Salida: <strong> 01/01/2023 </strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="label">Lugar o Ciudad: <strong>Cabimas Hotel Europa</strong></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="titulo">
            Observaciones 
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="display:flex">
            <div class="titulo" style="width:50%">
                Aprobado Por 
            </div>
            <div class="titulo" style="width:50%">
                Recibido Por 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="label">Nombre y Apellido del Supervisor Inmeadiato </div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="label"> Nombre y Apellido </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="label">Cargo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="label">Firma</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formbloq">
            <div class="campo" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="campo" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="label"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="display:flex">
            <div class="titulo" style="width:33.33%">
                Control y Gestion de Calidad
            </div>
            <div class="titulo" style="width:33.33%">
                Departamento de Reservaciones
            </div>
            <div class="titulo" style="width:33.33%">
                Junta Directiva
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:flex">
            <div class="sign" style="width:45%; display: flex;flex-direction:column; text-align: left">
                Nombre:
            </div>
            <div class="sign" style="width:30%; display: flex;flex-direction:column; text-align: left">
                Fecha:
            </div>
            <div class="sign" style="width:30%; display: flex;flex-direction:column; text-align: left">
                Firma:
            </div>
            <div class="sign" style="width:45%; display: flex;flex-direction:column; text-align: left">
                Nombre:
            </div>
            <div class="sign" style="width:30%; display: flex;flex-direction:column; text-align: left">
                Fecha:
            </div>
            <div class="sign" style="width:30%; display: flex;flex-direction:column; text-align: left">
                Firma:
            </div>
            <div class="sign" style="width:45%; display: flex;flex-direction:column; text-align: left">
                Nombre:
            </div>
            <div class="sign" style="width:30%; display: flex;flex-direction:column; text-align: left">
                Fecha:
            </div>
            <div class="sign" style="width:30%; display: flex;flex-direction:column; text-align: left">
                Firma:
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Me gustaria saber que esta ocasionando el error de manera que pueda imprimir una planilla pdf,

Comment: This looks like something that would happen if there's a syntactical error in your HTML. The result is that Dompdf doesn't quite know how to render the document. Either enable the [HTML5 parser](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/HTML5-Parser) or run your HTML through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 1):

"display : flex" isn't supported in dompdf library

Comment: While this is useful information, it doesn't quite answer the question.  Could you provide code that will accomplish the purpose of the original questioner?  Or if the solution is simply to remove those lines from the code, please put that in your answer!